# Secure PHP short Login API

Tags: php, rest

I have to do the Login API for an Angular Client. The only endpoint I need is to login. The data is not hyper sensible, I just want a simple solution, secure enough to know that nobody with bad intentions could break it easily.
I have some code, but I'm sure it's not good

```
<?php
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$servername = "localhost";
$usernameDB = "root";
$passwordDB = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $usernameDB, $passwordDB, "myDb");

header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('{
      "status": false,
      "error":'.$conn->connect_error .'
    }' );
}
$sql = "SELECT ID, Identificacion, Usuario, Contrasena FROM Usuarios ".
        "WHERE RptReparto_Habilitado = 1 and ".
        "Usuario = '". $user . "' and ".
        "Contrasena = '". $pass . "'";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
if ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo '{ "status": true,"id":'. $row['ID'] .' , "username": "'.$row['Usuario'].'", "identificacion": "'. $row['Identificacion'] . '"}';
} else {
    echo '{
      "status": false,
      "error": "'.$conn->error .'"
    }';
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I wanted to implement maybe Slim php, which my colleauges recommended.
Maybe hashing the password in the angular client. Implementing a function for the JSON creation, and checking for SQL Injection.

What's the cheapest option? Can I achieve all of that in plain PHP easily, or is it easier to implement a library?

Thank you!

Comment: The "cheapest" option is not to use any authentication at all. Better do it right than cheap!

Comment: I know, the cheapest without being a complete mess, the best price/quality relation option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use JWT.
https://jwt.io/
It's a authentication system only based on token.
First the user authenticate with his logins
After only a web token is used to keep the "session" open.
The token must be send for all the request you make with angular in the http header.

It's easier to use an existing library to do that

Comment: Thank you! Very useful information, I won't mark as answered because I still need a solution for SQL Injection

Comment: To avoid sql injection you can use PDO http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php, you have to make prepared query and pdo does all the rest